# Toggling of radio button only works once (refresh)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a radio box selection included in cells table.

The toggling works only once per radio button.

After, all radio buttons are disabled but my HTML code seems to be correct; the attribute `checked="checked"` is present.

Why is this not working?

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var $elem = $(this).children('input');               
    var name = $elem.attr('name');
    $('input[name='+name+']').each(function(){
       $(this).removeAttr('checked');                  
    }).promise().done(function(){                 
       $elem.attr('checked','checked');               
    });
});
```

And the image:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be using [**`prop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) as currently you are actually removing the attribute using `removeAttr()` instead of just setting it to disabled.

The following will work:

```
$('input[name='+name+']').each(function(){
   $(this).prop('checked', false);                  
}).promise().done(function(){                 
   $elem.prop('checked', true);               
});
```

Comment: `prop` do the trick, but I don't understand why `attr` doesn't refrech the UI??!!

Comment: I don't think that `removeAttr` is the cause. Actually, `$(this).attr('checked', false);` doesn't work too. I need to use `prop`. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @sdespont I don't think `attr('checked', false)` exists, the way to set checked to false using attr is to use `removeAttr`, so the problem is removeAttr I believe :)